# How to remove white space in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, entity, whitespace

In the following result `postId` field, I am getting white space `"post: 5a522414c963d600067392e4` after running the sql query but in database there is no any white space. In database there is no any white space, In database data is like this `post:5a522414c963d600067392e4`

```
Post {
    id : 4233 
    postId : " post: 5a522414c963d600067392e4 "
}
```

Please help me, how to get rid of this white space. I have used this query to find the result `findOneBy(array('id' =>$id)))`

Comment: You can try to use the `TRIM` function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_rtrim

Comment: Is it the result directly after the request? Did you `dump()` it?